# getting node value exception

Tags: java, dom

```
<amount currency="USD">1000500</amount>
```

while parsing above string i am getting only attribute value .when i try to get node value null pointer exception

for getting node value using

```
 NodeList amountList= estimateElement.getElementsByTagName("amount");
 Element amtElement= (Element)amountList.item(0);
 String amount=amtElement.getFirstChild().getnodevalue()
```

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Comment: @Andreas_D: You changed the question? Why?

Comment: @Thejh: Andreas fixed the display of the XML and code.

Comment: nothing serious - if we want to display xml/html fragments we *have* to use code formatting on those lines, otherwise the tags are not displayed. Click on the link after "edited" to the the [change history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4499397/revisions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. I assume that it is true:

```
 NodeList list = estimateElement.getElementsByTagName("amount").item(0).getChildNodes();
 Node node = (Node) list.item(0); 

 String value  = node.getNodeValue();
```

Source : [DOM parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Element amtElement= (Element)amountList.item(0);
```

seems to be your  element - so why are you calling getFirstChild()?

try this:

```
String amount=amtElement.getnodevalue()
```

have you checked out jdom? it has a nice documentation and is easy to use..

Comment: According to the docs getNodeValue returns null for an element. What he's doing actually looks correct per the docs.

Comment: can you post a link to the documentation.. which parser are you using?

Comment: I assume it's this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html

Comment: Thankq Stephan if i use amtElement.getnodevalue() returning null.but if i get value of attribute it is returning "USD"

Comment: yeah.. but at which point... if your amountList is already null.. then you have no chance on getting any further

Comment: amountlist is not null when i try to get node value it is returning null if i get attribute i am getting "USD"

Comment: Try: NodeList amountList= estimateElement.getElementsByTagName("amount");
 Element amtElement= (Element)amountList.item(0);
 Text amountNode=(Text)amtElement.getFirstChild(); String amount = amountNode..getnodevalue();

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `getTextContent()` method:

```
NodeList amountList= estimateElement.getElementsByTagName("amount");
Element amtElement= (Element)amountList.item(0);
String amount=amtElement.getTextContent();
```

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) for more info.

Comment: Uh Huh. It might help if you told us what DOM parser implementation you are actually using...

Comment: That's not the implementation. That's the interface an implementation implements (which apparently whatever implementation you are using doesn't adhere to). See this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html "Provides DOM interface"

Comment: If it does implement w3c.dom, then getTextContent will be supported: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29